# Using latest selenium ver with JAva 8 is giving LoggingHandler error

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to run a simple selenium script which open the chrome driver to navigate to the url. Below is my code:

```
WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
element.sendKeys("Cheese!!!");
element.submit();
System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
driver.quit();
```

On running the code I am getting the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/logging/LoggingHandler
at Main.main(Main.java:16)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingHandler
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
```

My pom file has these dependencies :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

What is causing the above error? I have tried searching online but can't find one answer to this.

Comment: which line throws this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error seems to be that it does not find the class `LoggingHandler`. That class is usually in the `selenium-api` dependency. You can try to use `2.53.1` version instead of `3.4.0`. That version has the missing class.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input . I was able to solve the problem by creating another new project and still using the same pom file.

Comment: This has moved me on to having another compilation error, so thank you. However, I'm wondering if anyone knows WHY this is occurring. Is it a Java error or a Selenium one?